# How is the global truncation error and stability criterion of the forward Euler method consistent with each other?

Tags: numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, eulers-method

The forward Euler method can be used to solve ODE's with some initial value by using the update rule

$$y_{k+1} = y_k + hf(t_k, y_k),$$
where $0\leq k \leq n-1$ and $h$ is the step size $\dfrac{t_n-t_0}{n}$. Reading from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), the global truncation error (the difference between the true value and approximate value at last time step) is said to be bounded by a value proportional to the step size $h$, provided the solution $y$ has a bounded second derivative and $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in its second argument. In particular, there does not seem to be any requirement on the step size $h$ for this to hold.

At the same time, it is said that the forward Euler method needs a sufficiently small step size $h$ in order to be numerically stable, i.e. for $h$ that is too large the numerical solution grows without bound while the exact solution decays to zero.

What confuses me is that I think this implies that the global truncation error is unbounded for some $h$ (since the numerical solution can grow without bound while the exact solution decays to zero), while at the same time the validity of the bound on the global truncation error seems to be independent of the value of $h$. This seems contradictory, what am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your objection is valid. In the error order computation one has to assume that $h$ is small enough. More precisely, one needs that the region where the Lipschitz constant and bound on the second derivative are taken contains the exact solution and the numerical solution for the range of $h\in[0,\bar h]$ under consideration.

If $\bar h$ increases, the numerical solution will have wilder deviations from the exact solution, as you said, and thus the region for the constants has to become larger. This again will increase the constants. As long as no division-by-zero is encountered, the error bound for the large step size $h=\bar h$ will again be correct, but it can become be horribly pessimistic for the smaller step sizes.

---

For the statements in the second half in the post, note that the claims in the first half and the considerations above are for a fixed integration interval of finite length. For large step sizes the error will lose its almost linear behavior and show growth that is polynomial in $h$. It will be rare to get actual divergence in this situation.

The divergence due to missing stability occurs for an unbounded integration interval. This divergence will be exponential or in the growth behavior of a geometric series. Mathematically this is slow, controlled. Numerically such a divergence can rapidly exhaust the range of the number type.